Produce to Confluent Kafka Topic with SASL_SSL and OAUTHBEARER mechanism using python client
I'm trying to produce one message to a topic in my RBAC-enabled and TLS-enabled Confluent Kafka cluster. My solution only works partially. I'm seeking help to successfully publish a message to the topic using the confluent-kafka library.
Broker config:
listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:SSL,REPLICATION:SSL,TOKEN:SASL_SSL
listeners=EXTERNAL://:9092,INTERNAL://:9071,REPLICATION://:9072,TOKEN://:9073
listener.name.token.sasl.enabled.mechanisms=OAUTHBEARER
confluent.metadata.server.authentication.method=BEARER
confluent.metadata.server.listeners=https://0.0.0.0:8090
confluent.metadata.server.token.auth.enable=true
kafka.rest.confluent.metadata.http.auth.credentials.provider=BASIC

Code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from confluent_kafka import Producer

def oauthbearer_refresh_cb(oauthbearer_config):
    url = "https://my-kafka-broker:8090/security/1.0/authenticate"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
    }
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('kafka', 'kafka-secret'), verify=False)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        token_info = response.json()
        token = token_info.get("auth_token")
        expires_in = token_info.get("expires_in", 3600) * 1000  # Convert to milliseconds
        print(f"Refreshed OAuth token: {token}, expires in {expires_in} milliseconds")
        return token, expires_in
    else:
        print(f"Failed to refresh OAuth token: {response.text}")

def acked(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print("Failed to deliver message: %s: %s" % (str(msg), str(err)))
    else:
        print("Message produced: %s" % (str(msg)))

def produce_message(producer, topic, message):
    producer.produce(topic, value=message, on_delivery=acked)
    producer.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {
        'bootstrap.servers': 'my-kafka-broker:9073',
        'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
        'sasl.mechanisms': 'OAUTHBEARER',
        'ssl.ca.location': '/app/assets/certs/ca/cacerts.pem',
        'oauth_cb': oauthbearer_refresh_cb,
    }
    producer = Producer(**config)
    produce_message(producer, 'kafka-inbox', 'Hello, Kafka!')

The output shows that the auth token is refreshed periodically, but publishing the message seems to be unsuccessful:
kafka@python-producer:/app/docker/producer$ ./producer_native.py 
/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1103: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'my-kafka-broker'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings
  warnings.warn(
Refreshed OAuth token: <actual-auth-token-redacted>, expires in 3600000 milliseconds
/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1103: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'my-kafka-broker'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings
  warnings.warn(
Refreshed OAuth token: <actual-auth-token-redacted>, expires in 3600000 milliseconds
...
^C^Z
[21]+  Stopped                 ./producer_native.py

The token header and payload retrieved looks like this:
kafka@python-producer:/app/docker/producer$ curl --silent -k -u kafka:kafka-secret -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"  -X GET https://my-kafka-broker:8090/security/1.0/authenticate | jq -r '.auth_t
oken | split(".") | .[0:2] | map(@base64d) | map(fromjson)'
[
  {
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": null
  },
  {
    "jti": "<redacted-actual-jti-value>",
    "iss": "Confluent",
    "sub": "kafka",
    "exp": 1712494519,
    "iat": 1712490919,
    "nbf": 1712490859,
    "azp": "kafka",
    "auth_time": 1712490919
  }
]

